# Simple one about package installation

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ because I need to use a package called Buddy. I'm not quite familiar with the compiling and the library things but I'm trying to learn. The thing is that the package is a bit old and all the instructions are based on Linux/g++, while I'm using Win10/VS2017. The installation instructions mention that:

1. Edit the file 'config' to specify your compiler and install option
2. Type make to make the binary
3. Type make install to copy the BDD files to their appropriate directories

Could you please help me with where I should do with the mentioned instructions? Or is it not possible to use this kind of package within VS2017?

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Search for _Makefile, build systems, GCC_ and similar.

Comment: If the package does not include a readme text file with instructions and makefiles for Windows it probably is not compatible.  Linux and Windows  are not compatible "under the hood."  Did you try a Google search to look for Windows instructions?

Comment: @DaveS Hell froze over and [Windows now supports Linux system calls](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/04/11/windows-10-creators-update-whats-new-in-bashwsl-windows-console/). If you've installed the "Creators Edition" you get a reasonably complete Ubuntu runtime.

Comment: @tadman - sure, but it sounds like the question is about trying to build and  install a Linux package in Windows itself not the Ubuntu subsystem.

Comment: @DaveS You can do that now if you use the right tools within the Windows environment. It may not be the best plan, but it will work. The alternative is booting up a Linux VM in HyperV, VirtualBox or VMWare.